# Keep lines from line X then delete others if does not contain pattern

Tags: powershell

I am trying to manipulate a textfile. I want it to keep the first X numbers of lines and after that it should look for a string pattern. If a line contains the pattern it should be kept otherwise deleted.

I got both things to work  separately but not together. It works to keep lines until X and remove the rest. And I got it to work to remove all lines except for lines with a pattern, but I can't get it to work for both together.

EDIT: here is the code:

```
$data = Get-Content test.md 
$newdata = ""
$n = 0
Foreach ($line in $data) {
    if ($n++ -ge 6) {
        $newdata += $line | Where{$_ -match '\[R\]'}
    } else {
        $newdata += $line 
    }
    $newdata += "  `r`n"
}
$newdata > test2.md
```

The problem is the lines are still there as empty lines. But they should be completely deleted.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = Get-Content test.md 
$newdata = ""
$n = 0
Foreach ($line in $data) {
    if ($n++ -gt 6) {
        if ($line -match '\[R\]') {
            $newdata += $line + "  `r`n"
        }
    } else {
        $newdata += $line + "  `r`n"
    }
}
$newdata > test2.md
```

got it to work like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
"test.md" | % {
    Get-Content $_ -TotalCount 6
    (Select-String -path $_ -match '\[R \]' -AllMatches).Line
} | Out-File test2.md -Encoding Ascii
```